# Передача state, Redux

Tags: reactjs, redux

Не могу разобраться, как получить доступ к state в Redux в дочерних компонентах React. Определяю склад для всего приложения в файле index.js, в файле app.js расписываю структуру. Тут содержаться все компоненты, в которых должны меняться состояния. Склад создается и виден в index.js. Но в компоненте List.js к этому складу нет доступа.Что я делаю не так, как исправить?

PS. Неужели для того, чтобы работать со складом в компонентах, которые находятся внутри всего приложения, нужно передавать склад как параметр: от index.js в app.js, от app.js в List.js.

index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import  ReactDom from 'react-dom';
import {connect,Provider} from 'react-redux'
import {createStore} from "redux";
import {reducer} from "./redux/reducer";

import App from './app.js'

const store = createStore(reducer,
    window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__ && window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__()
);

ReactDom.render(
    <Provider store={store}>
        <App/>
    </Provider>,
    document.getElementById('App')
);
```

app.js

```
    import React from 'react';
    import List from './components/List.js';

    export default function () {
     return(
            <section>
              <List props={props}/>
            </section>
        );
    }
```

List.js

```
import React from 'react';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';

const List = props => {
    console.log(props.getState());  // props.getState is not a function
    ...
};


const mapStateToProps = state => {
    console.log(state);
    return state
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, null)(List)
```

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте так.

---

*app.js*

```
import React from 'react';
import List from './components/List.js';

export default function () {
 return(
        <section>
          <List />
        </section>
    );
}
```

*List.js*

```
import React from 'react';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';

const List = props => {
   return console.log(props.globalState);
};


const mapStateToProps = state => {
   return {
      globalState: state // state - Ваш весь store
   }
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(List)
```